# Getting multiple variables in TensorFlow and other frameworks (overheads)

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, caffe, theano, cntk

If I have the following graph and want to get the values of tensors T1 and T2 in TF without eager execution, how would I do this? I only know of eval() or session.run() (running that twice could be an option) or tf.print(), but printing is not desired (for performance reasons).

[image: Example graph]

Especially, how is this functionality implemented in TensorFlow? Does this impose a big overhead towards just getting T2? I would be happy to be pointed to relevant resources as well.

I'm generally looking for discussions on this -- if people want to add comparisons to how other frameworks do this (Caffe, Torch, CNTK, Theano, Chainer, DyNet, etc.), that's great! In the end, I am trying to understand how these frameworks could be expanded by operators that return operator-specfic metrics that a user can use to monitor training.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass multiple parameters to session.run, and it will run the network once and return each of those parameters.

For example (from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session#run)):

```
   a = tf.constant([10, 20])
   b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0])
   u, v = session.run([a, b])
```